# Regex pattern for matching mm <sup>3<sup>

Tags: php, regex

I’m trying to write a regular expression to change mm<sup>3</sup> to mL:

```
<?php

$match = 'mm<sup>3</sup>';
if(preg_match('/\b(mm<sup>3</sup>)\b/', $match))
{
    $replacement = 'ml';
    $replac = preg_replace('/\b(mm<sup>3</sup>)\b/', $replacement, $match);
    echo $replac;
}

?>
```

But my regular expression doesn't capture the content in `$match` variable, and the `$replac` value isn't output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not `str_replace()` in this context ?

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran I want to use regex only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use `preg_quote` to get rid of that / in your regexp, or use a different delimiter (usually # is used).

Also, the \b separator after the > is not necessary, nor are parentheses since you don't seem to be doing capture; you're basically doing a more expensive `str_replace`.

Finally, you can do everything in one move. If there's no match, nothing will happen.

```
<?php
    $match = 'mm<sup>3</sup>';

    $replacement='ML';
    $replac = preg_replace('#\\bmm<sup>3</sup>#',
                       $replacement,
                       $match);
    echo $replac;
?>
```

If you want to be picky, I guess you should also replace with 'ml', not 'ML' :-)

(for replacement of multiple strings, `preg_replace` [supports arrays](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)).

**Note**: unless you're sure that is the correct HTML you want replaces, maybe you ought to try

```
$match = 'mm\\s*<sup>\\s*3\\s*</sup>';
```

in order to catch **mm <sup>3</sup>** and similar, in addition to **mm<sup>3</sup>** (in some circumstances they may look alike, and some editors might use or automatically "correct" either form into the other).

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
if(preg_match('/\b(mm<sup>3</sup>)\b/',$match))
```

to:

```
if(preg_match('#\bmm<sup>3</sup>\b#',$match))
```

and similarly in the `preg_replace` call.

Since your regular expression contains `/`, you need to either escape it or use a different delimiter around the regular expression.

There's also no need for the parentheses, since you're not doing anything with the groups.

Comment: i made the changes but it is not capturing mm<sup>3</sup>.